# send image from one server to another

Tags: python, sockets, opencv, encoding, base64

I want to send an image from one server to another. I don't want to save the file on disk. I directly want to read the send data. I've written a script for this.

**server.py**

```
import socket
import cv2

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("", 6002))

s.listen(10)
c, addr = s.accept()
print('{} connected.'.format(addr))

img = cv2.imread("test.jpg")
img = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)[1].tostring()

c.send( str(len(img)).ljust(16));
c.send(img)

i = 0
datas = img[i:i+1024]
i = i + 1024
while datas:
    datas = img[i:i+1024]
    c.send(datas)
    i = i + 1024

print("Done sending...")
```

**client.py**

```
import socket
import numpy as np

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("", 6002))

img = ""

while True:
    datas = s.recv(1024)
    while datas:
        img = img + str(datas)[2:-1]
        datas = s.recv(1024)
    break
print("Done receiving")
img_np = np.fromstring(img, np.uint8)
img_np = cv2.imdecode(img_np, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

I'm receiving image in `img` but when decoding it using opencv, I'm getting empty matrix `img_np`.

Comment: Why do you do `cv2.imread()`, which decompresses the JPEG on disk into a Numpy array, and then immediately call `cv2.imencode()` to recompress as JPEG in memory? You might as well just `read()` the file.

Comment: Check the length of the file you send and the file you receive too.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I thought of sending base64. I could have used `read()`, but it would have sent the image in binary. How would I then read the binary image on the client side in opencv ?

Comment: With `cv2.imdecode()` because that decompresses a JPEG. You don’t want base64, that will just make it 30% bigger for no reason.

Comment: Take a look at [imagezmq](https://github.com/jeffbass/imagezmq). Its a library to send OpenCV images over pyzmq

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use **Memory-Mapped File** instead of **ZeroMQ** as it yields less latency.
Here is an example I wrote that you can use: https://github.com/off99555/python-mmap-ipc